Dynamics 365 Business Central Batch transaction not working using REST API
I've been trying to create a batch transaction using the REST API and I can't get the transactional part to work, i.e. if I POST 2 entities, the first one succeeds, and the 2nd does not, the 1st is still created.
I've tried it with both JSON and multipart requests and got the same result.
As a side note, I've also been trying to reference previously-created entities in later ones in a transaction, but one thing at a time.
JSON request:
curl --request POST \\  
  --url 'https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/xxx/sandbox/api/v2.0/$batch' \\  
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer xxx' \\  
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \\  
  --header 'Isolation: snapshot' \\  
  --data '{  
      "requests": \[  
            {  
                  "method": "POST",  
                  "url": "vendors",  
                  "headers": {  
                        "Company": "TEST company",  
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",  
                        "Content-ID": "1",  
                        "If-Match": "\*"  
                  },  
                  "body": {  
                        "number": "15",  
                        "displayName": "Vendor 15"  
                  }  
            },  
            {  
                  "method": "POST",  
                  "url": "purchaseOrders",  
                  "headers": {  
                        "Company": "TEST company",  
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",  
                        "Content-ID": "1",  
                        "If-Match": "\*"  
                  },  
                  "body": {  
                        "vendorId": "$1"  
                  }  
            }  
      \]  
}'

Multipart request:
curl --request POST \\  
  --url 'https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/xxx/sandbox/api/v2.0/$batch' \\  
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \\  
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer xxx' \\  
  --header 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=batch_ABC123' \\  
  --header 'Isolation: snapshot' \\  
  --data '--batch_ABC123  
Content-Type: application/http  
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary  
Content-ID: 1

POST https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/xxx/sandbox/api/v2.0/companies(yyy)/vendors HTTP/1.1  
Content-Type: application/json;type=entry

{  
    "number": "27",  
    "displayName": "Vendor 27"  
}

\--batch_ABC123  
Content-Type: application/http  
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary  
Content-ID: 2

POST https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/xxx/sandbox/api/v2.0/companies(yyy)/purchaseOrders HTTP/1.1  
Content-Type: application/json;type=entry

{  
  "vendorId": "$1"  
}

\--batch_ABC123--'

Response:
{  
    "responses": \[  
        {  
            "id": "1",  
            "status": 201,  
            "headers": {  
                "location": "https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/xxx/sandbox/api/v2.0/companies(yyy)/vendors(asdf)",  
                "content-type": "application/json; odata.metadata=minimal; odata.streaming=true",  
                "odata-version": "4.0"  
            },  
            "body": {  
                "@odata.context": "https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/xxx/sandbox/api/v2.0/$metadata#companies(yyy)/vendors/$entity",  
                "@odata.etag": "W/\\"asdf=\\"",  
                "id": "asdf",  
                "number": "27",  
                "displayName": "Vendor 27",  
                "addressLine1": "",  
                "addressLine2": "",  
                "city": "",  
                "state": "",  
                "country": "",  
                "postalCode": "",  
                "phoneNumber": "",  
                "email": "",  
                "website": "",  
                "taxRegistrationNumber": "",  
                "currencyId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",  
                "currencyCode": "USD",  
                "irs1099Code": "",  
                "paymentTermsId": "asdf",  
                "paymentMethodId": "asdf",  
                "taxLiable": true,  
                "blocked": "\_x0020\_",  
                "balance": 0,  
                "lastModifiedDateTime": "2024-07-25T15:18:56.157Z"  
            }  
        },  
        {  
            "id": "2",  
            "status": 400,  
            "headers": {  
                "content-type": "application/json",  
                "content-length": "163"  
            },  
            "body": {  
                "error": {  
                    "code": "BadRequest",  
                    "message": "Cannot convert the literal '$1' to the expected type 'Edm.Guid'.  CorrelationId:  fc3b4859-5a26-451c-ba81-4e6365a535bc."  
                }  
            }  
        }  
    \]  
}

If I try either of the 2 requests above again, I get a new error that the vendor with the given ID already exists, so the transacton is obviously not being rolled back when the second entity fails:
{
    "responses": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "atomicityGroup": "3ef07230-5a80-4620-9834-a89c42477bf8",
            "status": 400,
            "headers": {
                "content-type": "application/json",
                "content-length": "205"
            },
            "body": {
                "error": {
                    "code": "Internal_EntityWithSameKeyExists",
                    "message": "The record in table Vendor already exists. Identification fields and values: No.='27'  CorrelationId:  5e756e24-4fb9-41a8-b3ee-16987f4a7dd3."
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

